# Razor/Blazor cannto access custom js function

Tags: javascript, html, css, razor, blazor

*I'm using Radzen, which uses Blazor which uses Razor, which uses bootstrap.*

I have a *.js* file called *jsFuncs* which contain a function:

```
function myJSFunction() {
//irrelevant code for this question
}
```

Inside the *index.html* file (located under *wwwroot*) i have this:

```
<body>
   //irrelevant code for this question
   <script src="jsFuncs.js"></script>
</body>
```

Inside the *Index.razor* i have this at the top of the page:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime Js
@using System.Globalization
```

and in the same file i have this function:

```
private async Task JsPrint()
{
    await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("myJSFunction");
}
```

But this does not work. I get the error; "Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'myJSFunction' ('myJSFunction' was undefined).".
What am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the function in the global scope with:

```
window.myJSFunction = () => {
    //irrelevant code for this question
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I have seen multipe different posts who did it the way i did it in my question. With "function myJSFunction()", why do they say that? Is there a way to get that to work too? Or is it Radzen/Blazor that makes it so that i have to do it the way you said it?
Would like to know why

Comment: np ^^ in my understanding it has to do with the scope of the function. you can try putting the `export` keyword in front of "function myJSfunc()" or directly including the function inside the index.html script tag.